# chartjs default background color to columns

Tags: charts, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

Hello how i can set default background color to dataset columns? like on image. 
The gray part of columns. So every columns will have gray background color from 0 to max value.

[image]

Here is the code of my data chart. I look the examples on chart.js site but there i can't find anythin about this situation

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("data");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Today', '12 Th', '13 Fr', '14 St', '15 Sn', '16 Mn', '17 Tu'],
        datasets: [{
                label: 'Capacity',
                data: [20.7, 10, 40, 2, 100, 43, 34],
                backgroundColor: '#43d100'
            },
            {
                label: 'Confirmed',
                data: [11.4, 100, 20, 42, 10, 20, 65],
                backgroundColor: '#dc1f1f'
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        layout: {
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    drawBorder: false
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    display: false,
                    max: 200,
                    fill: "#07C"
                },
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    drawBorder: false
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @WhiteHat hello, my question is updated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an option doesn't exist for column background color.
a third series will need to be added to represent the background.
which can easily be done by subtracting the original values from the max value.
the tooltip for the background series can be removed by using the `filter` option.

see following working snippet...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // original datasets
    var chartData = [{
        label: 'Capacity',
        data: [20.7, 10, 40, 2, 100, 43, 34],
        backgroundColor: '#43d100'
    },
    {
        label: 'Confirmed',
        data: [11.4, 100, 20, 42, 10, 20, 65],
        backgroundColor: '#dc1f1f'
    }];

    // max value - background dataset
    var maxValue = 200;
    var maxData = {
        label: 'Max',
        data: [],
        backgroundColor: '#cccccc'
    };

    // subtract each dataset value from max value
    chartData.forEach(function (dataset) {
        dataset.data.forEach(function (value, index) {
            if (maxData.data.length <= index) {
                maxData.data.push(maxValue);
            }
            maxData.data[index] -= value;
        });
    });

    // add background dataset
    chartData.push(maxData);

    var ctx = document.getElementById("data");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Today', '12 Th', '13 Fr', '14 St', '15 Sn', '16 Mn', '17 Tu'],
            datasets: chartData  // <-- modified dataset
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            layout: {
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    stacked: true,
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false,
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        drawBorder: false
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    stacked: true,
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        display: false,
                        max: 200,
                        fill: "#07C"
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false,
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        drawBorder: false
                    }
                }]
            },
            // remove tooltip for background dataset
            tooltips: {
                filter: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                    return (tooltipItem.datasetIndex < (chartData.length - 1));
                },
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="data"></canvas>
```

Comment: Can you tell me if you have a similar example for react char using Chartjs and Bar graph? I will really appreciate it.

Comment: there shouldn't be any difference for react, since the main feature is in the data being fed to the chart. and the tooltips can be added to the options as done here.